# show field_name from joined table instead of field_id in yajra datatables that generated from infyom

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

i have

- payments datatable with field 'id', 'transaction_id', 'date','amount', 'payment_method_id', 'additional_note'
- payment_methods table with field 'id', 'name','code'

what i want to achieve is in payment datatable it show payment_method->name instead of payment_method_id

Here is my datatables code

```
 <?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Payment;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;

class PaymentDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'payments.datatables_actions');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Post $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(Payment $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->addAction(['width' => '120px'])
            ->parameters([
                'dom'     => 'Bfrtip',
                'order'   => [[0, 'desc']],
                'buttons' => [
                    ['extend' => 'create', 'className' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm no-corner',],
                    ['extend' => 'export', 'className' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm no-corner',],
                    ['extend' => 'print', 'className' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm no-corner',],
                    ['extend' => 'reset', 'className' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm no-corner',],
                    ['extend' => 'reload', 'className' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm no-corner',],
                ],
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'transaction_id',
            'date',
            'amount',
            'payment_method_id',
            'additional_note'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'paymentsdatatable_' . time();
    }
}
```

I have search around and know that it had to do something in

```
 public function query(Payment $model)
        {
            return $model->newQuery();
        }
```

but haven't found worked solution.. maybe any suggestion

nb: i have post issued asking about it here https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues/582 too but no respons back yet

Comment: this tutorial may help https://youtu.be/sJrDpFl3Pcw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used Yajra tables in a while, but I did something like this. Depending on how you named the relationship between `Payment` and `PaymentMethod`, modify this to suit your situation.

```
public function query(Payment $model)
{
    return $model->newQuery()->with(['paymentMethod']);

    // specify columns if you like
    // return $model->newQuery()->with(['paymentMethod'])->select('payments.*');
}

...

protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'transaction_id',
        'date',
        'amount',
        [
            'name' => 'paymentMethod.name',
            'data' => 'paymentMethod.name',
            'title' => 'Payment Method',
            'defaultContent' => '',
        ],
        'additional_note',
    ];
}
```

Comment: return $model->newQuery()->with(['paymentMethod']);
"paymentMethod" supposed to be the model name? or reference on what?

Comment: as for how to get the columns seems it true written.. i have done my search and resulting same thing, but how to do the query is the one i stuck at

Comment: and as i try it up.. it still give me blank for the payment_method.name

Comment: @user2180614 `paymentMethod` is the method defined on your `Payment` model to return a relationship to the `PaymentMethod` model. How did you setup that relationship?

Comment: hmm i define it like this 
 public function paymentmethod()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PaymentMethod','payment_method_id');
    }
and no error but no payment_method.name displayed

Comment: aah i found the problems the 'data' => 'payment_method.name' should be using the relation not the table name so 'data' => 'paymentMethod.name',
edit your answer dude.. and i will mark it as answered

Comment: Done. I seem to remember having to use snake_case for that. But like I said, it's been a while, so they may have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

**To display relationship data into Yajra DataTables with InfyOm Laravel Generator**

need to Modify **getColumn()** method on your datatable file.

```
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'title',
        'author_name' => new \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column(['title' => 'Author Name', 'data' => 'author.name', 'name' => 'author.name'])
    ];
}
```

and Modify **query** method to return relationship data

```
public function query(Post $model)
{
    return $model->newQuery()->with(['author']);
}
```

here its full blog with example: https://blog.infyom.com/how-to-display-relationship-data-into-yajra-datatables-with-infyom-laravel-generator